# Есть ли мужской вариант имени Людмила?

Tags: имена-собственные

Есть ли мужской вариант имени Людмила?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русской традиции - нет. Однако в Болгарии есть мужское имя Людмил.

Answer (score 0):

По версии Павла Флоренского, имя Людмила для героических женщин. Она может быть даже грубиянкой, но также сестрой милосердия, фельдшером, защитницей слабых. Исходя из этого, можно сделать вывод, что мужские черты в имени есть, но мужского варианта я не нашла.